# Get value from enum based on another enum key in Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have two enums that have exact same keys, but in these keys they keep different values.

```
export enum HistoricalRatesEnpoints {
  ONE_DAY = '1-day/15m',
  ONE_WEKK = '7-days/1h',
  ONE_MONTH = '1-month/1d',
  THREE_MONTHS = '3-months/1d',
  SIX_MONTHS = '6-months/1d',
  ONE_YEAR = '1-year/1d',
}

export enum Ranges {
  ONE_DAY = '1 day',
  ONE_WEEK = '1 week',
  ONE_MONTH = '1 month',
  THREE_MONTHS = '3 months',
  SIX_MONTHS = '6 months',
  ONE_YEAR = '1 year',
}

...

 function getKeyByValue(value: string) {
    const index = Object.values(Ranges).indexOf(value as unknown as Ranges);
  
    const key = Object.keys(Ranges)[index];
  
    return key;
  }

const key = getKeyByValue(Ranges.ONE_DAY) // gives 'ONE_DAY' key (string type)
HistoricalRatesEnpoints[key] // want to return '1-day/15min'
```

Function getKeyBayValue returns 'ONE_DAY" key (type string). Because HistoricalRatesEndpoints has the same keys i want to get a value from HistoricalRatesEnpoints base on Ranges key. Is it possible to get a value from enum based on another enum key if they have the same keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function that returns type guard (I recommend double check this):

```
function getKeyByValue(value: Ranges): string {
    const index = Object.values(Ranges).indexOf(value);
    return Object.keys(Ranges)[index];
}

function isHistoricalRatesEnpoints(key: string): key is keyof typeof HistoricalRatesEnpoints {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(HistoricalRatesEnpoints, key)
}

const key = getKeyByValue(Ranges.ONE_DAY)

if (isHistoricalRatesEnpoints(key)) {
    HistoricalRatesEnpoints[key] // type of `key` inferred here
}
```

Or you can just cast

```js
HistoricalRatesEnpoints[key as keyof typeof HistoricalRatesEnpoints]
```

Or cast in function return type:

```js
function getKeyByValue(value: Ranges) {
    const index = Object.values(Ranges).indexOf(value);
    return Object.keys(Ranges)[index] as keyof typeof HistoricalRatesEnpoints;
}
```